# Append to a json file in windows application

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have created a Json format file in windows application using newtonsoft.the code is working and the json is creating fine.But I want to append the new file to the old json file,now it is replacing.here is my code

```
List<DeviceData> tempDate = new List<DeviceData>();
DeviceData D = new DeviceData();
D.deviceId = St_Id.ToString();
D.ansId = AnswerStr;
tempDate.Add(D);
string ans = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(tempDate, Formatting.Indented);
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"E:\" + " device.json", ans);
```

can any one help.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation, the method writeAllText Creates a new file, writes the specified string to the file, and then closes the file. If the target file already exists, it is overwritten.

To achieve what you want you need to do a check whether the file exists or not

```
string ans = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(tempDate, Formatting.Indented);
if (File.Exists(@"E:\" + " device.json")
  File.AppendAllText(@"E:\" + " device.json", appendText);
else
  System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"E:\" + " device.json", ans);
```

Comment: Hi, Sorry the format having some wrong.The string append to the device.json as


[
  {
    "deviceId": "2",
    "ansId": "2",
    "date": "2014-11-10T15:30:58.7717853+05:30"
  }
][
  {
    "deviceId": "4",
    "ansId": "1",
    "date": "2014-11-10T15:31:00.8717853+05:30"
  }
]

Comment: but how do you get the brackets [] at the top and the end of a file?

Answer (score 1):

use `File.AppendAllLines` docs and example is on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383691(v=vs.110).aspx)

`System.IO.File.AppendAllLines(@"E:\" + " device.json", ans);`

BTW: You should consider about deserialization of file's content.