# How to insert into json file without deleting the previous data?

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I am insert data into `.json` file. My insertion works fine, but I have a problem - when I insert new data, the previous data in the file is deleted. 
How can I manage that? 
Also I would need it to be in the format of because I need to query it:

```
[
  {
    "Rollnumber": 3,
    "StudentName": "Tapas"
  },
  {
    "Rollnumber": 4,
    "StudentName": "Papas"
  }
]
```

When I pass the data as the list.ToArray()(that would be the _data in the code example) I get the [] brackets, but only on the first data with rollnumber = 3.
This is my code so far:

```
private void AddStudent()
{
    Student objStudent = new Student();
    objStudent.Rollnumber = 3;
    objStudent.StudentName = "Tapas";


    /*  List<Student> _data = new List<Student>();
    _data.Add(new Student()
    {
        Rollnumber = 4,
        StudentName = "Papas"
    });
    */

    string jsonData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(objStudent, Formatting.Indented);
    System.IO.File.WriteAllText(jsonFileS, jsonData);
}
```

I have tried with the `StreamWritter` also, but I could not do it.

Comment: You could use `File.AppendAllText(jsonFileS, jsonData);` instead. It'll append to the file if it does exist or create a new one otherwise.

Comment: When you want to add new data to JSON, or change existing data, you should load the source file, then update the data and save the new values. JSON is not a format that allow a simple "append" *(this is possible only in a few formats e.g. CSV)*. How to do this? This depends on the JSON framework you use.

Comment: @Julo do you have some example on how to do it?

Comment: Your file has an array, if you append to it, you will have an array and whatever else you appended to it. If you always need one array in the file, Everytime you need to modify the file, desrialize the contents of the file into a list, add to the list،  then serialize the entire list back to the file.

Comment: Unfortunately I do not know the JSON library your are using. And i'm afraid, it is not possible with a library meant for serialisation of classes _(at least not without deserialising of the previous content)_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is on this link : [append to a json file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26839654/append-to-a-json-file-in-windows-application)

```
   var jsonData = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(jsonFile);
        // De-serialize to object or create new list
        var employeeList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Student>>(jsonData)
                              ?? new List<Student>();

        // Add any new employees
        employeeList.Add(new Student()
        {
            Rollnumber = 1,
            StudentName = "Paja1",
            Subject = new Subject
            {
                Id = 1,
                Name = "Sub1"
            }
        });
        employeeList.Add(new Student()
        {
            Rollnumber = 1,
            StudentName = "Pera1",
            Subject = new Subject
            {
                Id = 1,
                Name = "Sub1"
            }
        });

        // Update json data string
        jsonData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(employeeList,Formatting.Indented);
        System.IO.File.WriteAllText(jsonFile, jsonData);
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Retrieve the source file that containing JSON.
2. Read text content (JSON data) from source file.
3. Deserialize JSON data to List of student object.
4. Add new student student list.
5. Serialize the student list, you will get JSON data string as return from that method.
6. Save JSON string to the source file.

Here is example code:

```
var file = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync(fileName);
var jsonString = await FileIO.ReadTextAsync(file);
var studentList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Student>>(jsonString);
var newStudent = new Student();
newStudent.Rollnumber = 2;
newStudent.StudentName = "Abcd";
studentList.Add(newStudent);
var updatedJsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(studentList);
await FileIO.WriteTextAsync(file, updatedJsonString);
```

Comment: This is something like a solution  that I have posted. Thanks

Comment: Actually i didn't see that... Sorry

Answer (score 1):

I think in your situation, you can do a little trick like :

1, Read data from file

```
StreamReader sw = new StreamReader(fileName);
string res = sw.ReadToEnd();
```

2, Remove the "]" of the "res"(res variable) and add new Json string(remove the "[" and add ",") with your format.

So your string will look like two strings bellow adding together

```
[
  {
    "Rollnumber": 3,
    "StudentName": "Tapas"
  }
// Cut the last "]"
```

and

```
// cut the first "[" and add ","
      ,
      {
        "Rollnumber": 4,
        "StudentName": "Papas"
      }
    ]
```

So it will become what you want in the final :

```
[
  {
    "Rollnumber": 3,
    "StudentName": "Tapas"
  },
  {
    "Rollnumber": 4,
    "StudentName": "Papas"
  }
]
```

Comment: Yeah,that is one way to do it! :)

Comment: I don't want to DeserializeObject json string because it will take a lot of time if your json string is too long, so this trick I think it is better.

Comment: @Alexander: but remember, this will only add new data and it will work only when there is no 'new line' character in the file _(when there is a new line character, you need to remove more character until it will reach the `]` character)_. And most important thing is, that this can be used only to append new data. It will not reflect changes in existing data _(new values in existing records)_.

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in my comments to your question, you need to either load the entire file, deserialize it and then add items to it in memory. Once done, rewrite to the file by serializing it.

If you do not want to load the entire file into memory, then work with the file manually by manipulating the serialized string and then append to the file; else you will end up with bad JSON in file.

Here is the first method wherein you deserialize the entire file:

```
public static class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var rolls = LoadRolls();

        // Once the contents of the file are in memory you can also manipulate them         
        Roll firstRoll = rolls.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Rollnumber == 1);
        if (firstRoll != null)
        {
            firstRoll.StudentName = "Jerry";
        }

        // Let's just add a few records. 
        rolls.AddRange(
            new List<Roll>{
                new Roll { Rollnumber = 1, StudentName = "Elaine" },
                new Roll { Rollnumber = 2, StudentName = "George" }
            });

        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(rolls, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);

        File.WriteAllText("Rolls.txt", json);

        Console.Read();
    }

    private static List<Roll> LoadRolls()
    {
        List<Roll> rolls = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Roll>>(File.ReadAllText("Rolls.txt"));

        return rolls ?? new List<Roll>();
    }
}

public class Roll
{
    public int Rollnumber { get; set; }
    public string StudentName { get; set; }
}
```